# Problems in loop with risetime: Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, signal-processing

I'm trying to calculate the rise time of 10000 pulses given as a matrix of size 80x10000.

I have tried to use the function `risetime` from the Signal Processing Toolbox.

For calculation I use this code:

```
for k=1:length(PS1)
    PS2(:,k) = risetime(PS1(:,k),80);
end
```

As a result I get the error message:

> Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

The resulting matrix `PS2` is of size 1x1011.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having an example data set I think that one of your pulses is returning more than 1 rise or returning `[]` because nothing was found.  `risetime` [see doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/risetime.html) will return a vector for the number of rises found within a given signal.

So as its progressing through your loop if the 1st signal had only 1 rise then the next has 2 then the number of right hand results doesn't match the left hand assignment ... assuming you pre-allocated `PS2` somewhere.

You could try defining PS2 as a cell array to figure out which pulse is returning more than the expected number (or zero) results.

```
PS2 = cell(size(PS1,2),1);
for k=1:size(PS1,2)
    PS2{k} = risetime(PS1(:,k),80);
end
```

If you really only want the first rise time then you would need a temporary var and only take the first element ... then do something else in the event your temp var comes out as empty (replace with NaN )  Example:

```
PS2 = nan(size(PS1,2),1);
for k=1:size(PS1,2)
    temp = risetime(PS1(:,k),80);
    if ~isempty(temp)
        PS2(k) = temp(1);
    end
end
```

EDIT:  Also note I replaced `length` with `size(..,2)` to get the number of columns. I personally don't like using length as it just returns the longest dimension.  So if you have really long signals or not that many pulses to evaluate you might run into issues.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need.